# Avoid code duplication when using .resize() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery script consisting of 100 lines or so. When a browser is opened it has a specific width and height, using these values the script calculates positions for various HTML elements.

**Problem:**

After the browser calculates the position values AND if the browser is resized, the positions of elements are messed up because the render is based on the width and height of browser before resizing.

I've put all the code inside `resize()` function but **another problem** is, the code inside `resize()` will only execute when the browser is resized and not when the browser is first launched.

Is there any way I can bind events like -

```
if( $(document).ready() OR $(window).resize() ) {
. . .
}
```

Comment: Create a function that does everything. On Document ready call it. On resize call it. Whats the problem?

Comment: Call your resize function on the document ready event:

$(document).ready(function() { [your_resize]();});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must to define a function with all your code and then call it in various events:

```
function stuff() {
  // all stuff;
}

$(document).ready(stuff);
$(window).resize(stuff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is way to late but a good point to see the Module Pattern. So define a function once and call it from where ever you like.

```
var WRAP = (function () {

    var myFunction = function (text) {
        console.log(text);
    };

    var myOtherFunction = function() {
        console.log('does nothing');
    };

    return {
        callMyFunction: myFunction,
        myOtherFunction: myOtherFunction
    };

})();

WRAP.callMyFunction('Loaded');
WRAP.myOtherFunction();

$(window).resize(function(){
    WRAP.callMyFunction('Resized');
});
```

[Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7cty2ytq/](http://jsfiddle.net/7cty2ytq/) and a good read: http://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/

Answer (score -2):

First bind resize event then trigger it on document.ready().
Have a look at my code

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
    alert('Window is resized');
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```